# An internal error has occured

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm Vaijanath. I'm using cakephp installed on lamp. Now i have created a blog application, but when i run this on `localhost/cakephpproject/cakephp/` it is showing an error:

```
"An Internal Error Has Occured".
```

And i had changed the "routes.php" in "/app/Config/routes.php" from

```
"Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));"
```

to

```
"Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));"
```

This is an internal error and i'm not able to solve it. Could you please help me in this?

Comment: First: do you have an index action in PostsController? Second, do you have the debug variable set to >= 1 to get a more detailed error?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project in your user's public_html dir ?

If so, you must update the three .htaccess files, located in `<projectBase>/`, `<projectBase>/app/` and `<projectBase>/app/webroot`, and add the following code after each `RewriteEngine on` statement :

```
RewriteBase /~<yourUserName>/<projectBase>/
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your CakePHP app in the ‘config’ folder change the following setting in the ‘core.php’ file
Configure::write(‘debug’, 0);
Change the ’0′ value to a ’2′ and CakePHP will print all debug errors.

It will display all the errors.. and when the functions works then again change it back to 0.